# Android Studio: Best way to store data set?

Tags: android, arrays, save, sharedpreferences

I know how to handle SharedPreferences, but I wonder about how to save more data at once.
For example my game app the user owns multiple cars with different stats.
What would be the best way to save the user having car01 with speed 3 and handling 2 and another car car02 with speed 1 and handling 1?

Is it possible to put multidimensional Arrays into SharedPreferences?
Can you show me a really simple example code?

Comment: Either a configuration file in some easy to parse format like JSON or a database, depending on how you want to look up the data and the amount of data.  Not enough info to tell you which is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Here is some snippet i found useful when i needed to use this.

```
String[][] my_date;

my_arr = new String[][] {
            {"14","26"},
            {"12","16","24","27"},
            {"17"},
            {"8","13","18"},
            {"14"},
            {},
            {"29"},
            {"15","18"},
            {},
            {"2","3","6","8","23"},
            {"4","6","24"},
            {}

SharedPreferences pref = arg0.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
Set<String> myStrings = pref.getStringSet("my_arr", new HashSet<String>());
myStrings.add("data");
editor.putStringSet("myStrings", myStrings);
editor.commit();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful :)

Comment: glad it helped you